# =VLOOKUP("*"&... is not working properly what am I doing wrong?

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

Trying to check a number in a cell against a column and get the value in the cell next to it. This works with an exact match, but I cant get it to work when trying to match part of a value in a cell.

Trying to check a number in a cell against a column and get the value in the cell next to it. This works with an exact match, but I cant get it to work when trying to match part of a value in a cell.

Example that works:

```
=VLOOKUP(E6;A:B;2;FALSE)
```

This checks cell E6 against column A for an exact match and delivers the value in column B.

Example that doesn´t work:

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&E6&"*";A:B;2;FALSE)
```

This should check cell E6 against column A for a partial match.
For example E6=ABS  should match 11ABS22 but this fails.

Cant figure out why, I have tried using

```
'*'&E6&'*'
```

with same result.

LOST HERE PLEASE HELP! :)

Comment: Your formula looks correct, as partial matches with wildcards must have a FALSE (or 0) in the fourth argument.  I did a quick test and got this working fine with minimal data.  When you say it doesn't work do you mean you get "N/A", an error, the wrong match, nothing?

Comment: I get a #N/A, when I use =VLOOKUP("*"&E8&"*";A1:B20;2;0)

Comment: If your lookup column contains numbers it will not find anything because the lookup value is text.

Comment: AHA, damn...
Only tested with random numbers :D
This solved it

Answer (score 0):

For a partial match, have you tried:

```
=VLOOKUP(E6;A:B;2;TRUE)
```

As the true, false argument switches between a partial match (True) and an exact match (false)

If you then want the result from a cell "next" to it and it is on the same row then change from two columns to 3 ie A:B to A:C and put 3 instead of 2.

So, another approach is to use a helper column, which will extract the 3 letters using mid() as shown:
[image]

Another possibility is to use offset()...

Comment: No this is for an exact match. for a partial match I tired to use =VLOOKUP("*"&E8&"*";A1:B20;2;0)

Comment: Well, show us some "real" data so we can better understand what you want. A "before" and "after" would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick screenshot of me doing pretty much what you want to do, and it working.  So you must be doing something wrong, or your Excel is broken, or you have an option not set the same way as me, or you have Unicode in your cells, or auto-calc turned off, etc.?

[image: VLOOKUP]

Comment: ...or you aren't actually checking "ABS" against "11ABS22" :P

Answer (score -1):

This would be for exact match:

```
=VLOOKUP(E6;A:B;2;FALSE)
```